# Splay Trees - Sequential Access Theorem & lower bound for comparison-based sorting

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-trees, amortized-analysis, splay-trees

The following theorem was proven by [R.E. Tarjan in 1984](https://Tarjan,%20Robert%20E.%20(1985).%20%22Sequential%20access%20in%20splay%20trees%20takes%20linear%20time%22.%20Combinatorica.%205%20(4):%20367%E2%80%93378.%20doi:10.1007/BF02579253.%20S2CID%2034757821.):

> **Theorem (Sequential Access Theorem).** If we access each of the nodes of an arbitrary initial tree once, in symmetric order, the total time spent is $O(n)$

But if we remove the smallest element one at a time, then does it imply that we sorted the element in $O(n)$ time? Of course not, because then it contradicts the following Theorem.

> Any comparison sort algorithm requires $\Omega(n\lg n)$ comparisons in the worst case.

What was wrong with the way I tried to use the Sequential Access Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in saying that if you access the nodes of a BST (not necessarily a splay tree) in symmetric order in time $O(n)$ then the sequence of the corresponding elements is sorted.

However this alone is not enough to obtain a sorting algorithm that runs in time $O(n)$ since you're disregarding the time needed to construct the tree itself.

In fact, your observation shows that the time spent to build a BST from an unsorted set of elements must be $\Omega(n \log n)$ in the worst case.